# Cannot access internet via WiFi, but 'apt-get' works fine!

Tags: networking, wifi, pi-2

I am very new to Linux environment and to networking. I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian.

The problem is, when I am connecting to the Internet via WiFi dongle (comfast, actually, I had pretty much struggled to get its driver installed and work) I can connect to WiFi, and do the following:

```
ping www.google.com
apt-get update
apt-get install [...]
```

I can even browse 'pi store' with with the included app. Everything is fine until I try to reach some web address like:

```
wget http://something.com/something.tar.gz
```

It returns:

```
cannot resolve hostname
```

It does the same when I open browser and enter an IP address.

Comment: What is comfast?

Comment: sorry to make you confused. it is just the name of my wifi dongle. comfast cf-wu810n

Comment: Are you saying you can ping for example, www.google.com but can't browse to for example, www.google.com? i.e. ping *host-name* works, but browsing to the **same** *host-name* does not

Comment: yes. definitely.

Comment: as I mentioned above, I can't use 'wget' in terminal,

Comment: Are you sure that `ping www.google.com` works from the shell?  What about some other arbitrary hostname such as `ping www.yahoo.com`.

Comment: when I typed 'ping www.yahoo.com' it returns 'ping ir-ds-any-fp3-lfb.wal.b.yahoo.com (206.190. )..etc . . .. ( ) bytes of data'. Doesn't it means it work?

Comment: By any chance, browser is configured to work with a proxy or something ?

Comment: nope. I don't touch any of these configurations, dastaan.

Comment: Does www.google.com work in your browser?

Comment: no, nothing works in browser.

Comment: does `dig google.com` work?

Comment: is that command exist? I am now using raspbian. when i type dig google.com, it returns dig: command not found

Comment: install `dnsutils`, then you will have it

Comment: Thanks for answer, Diederik de Haas! but, unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. Is there any way around?